# How to set correct root path when use Github Actions ci/cd?

Tags: jestjs, github-actions

I am trying to use ci/cd workflow with github Actions,

I use jest for unit test and set `moduleNameMapper` like below:

```
  "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
        "^components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1"
   }
```

I can run `npm test` successfully in local, However github actions always get error:

```
Could not locate module src/components/tool-panel/Container.vue (mapped as /home/runner/work/its-me/its-me/src/components/tool-panel/Container.vue)

Please check:

"moduleNameMapper": {
  "/^src\/(.*)$/": "/home/runner/work/its-me/its-me/src/$1"
},
"resolver": undefined
```

Seems the `<rootDir>` is replaced as `/home/runner/work/its-me/its-me`, and there no folder `src` in this path:  `/home/runner/work/its-me/its-me`.

So How can i set correct root path?

I am not sure if i can ssh to github action server.

This is my github repo: [It's me](https://github.com/jeoy/its-me)

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are referencing the file `Container.vue` with an uppercase `C` but the actual file is all lowercase. If your local filesystem is case insensitive it may execute fine.

https://github.com/jeoy/its-me/blob/master/test/unit/toolContainer.spec.js#L8

Change the filename here to all lowercase:

```
import Container from 'src/components/tool-panel/Container.vue';
```